# why document.getElementById for input type=text failed

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to get data from form using getElementById. It works if i get from select form(like below), but why it fails when i try to get from textbox?

```
<select name="permission" id="permission" class="select2">
    <option value="rw">Read &amp; Write</option>
    <option value="r">Read Only</option>
</select>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var x= document.getElementById("permission").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

If I change "permission" to "tenants" to get from below textbox, it doesn't show. I am confused ._.

```
<input type="text" id="tenants" name="tenants" class="form-control">
```

Comment: How you are trying for textbox? Can we see?

Comment: <script>
  var x= document.getElementById("tenants").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  </script>

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/27ty49rp/2/)?

Comment: "If i change 'summary' to 'tenants'", where is `'summary'` in the code you posted?

Comment: see my edit. shud be permission not summary my bad.

Comment: _“it doesn't show”_ - what “it”? If you are executing this on page load, then what value do you expect the input field to have?

Comment: the value in textbox. the value is there, im using ajax and query. i just want to extract the value in the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="tenants" name="tenants" class="form-control">
```

If you want to get a value from this above code, use this.

```
var x = document.getElementById("tenants").value;
```

Looking at your original script

```
<select name="permission" id="permission" class="select2">
    <option value="rw">Read &amp; Write</option>
    <option value="r">Read Only</option>
</select>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  var x= document.getElementById("permission").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

This code only gets the value from `select` with an id `permission` and store it to `p` with an id `demo`.

Comment: Yes that what i did. But i noticed i cannot get the input value unless i put value="something" then it will show "something". The problem is the data i get is from ajax page and query from database. How can i solve this yeah.

Comment: maybe you should put the ajax code and query to your question

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```js
  function tenants_change(){
  var x= document.getElementById("tenants").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
tenants_change();
```

```html
<input type="text"  id="tenants" name="tenants" value="value" onchange="tenants_change()" class="form-control">
  <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
<input type="text"  id="permission" name="tenants" class="form-control">
```

Comment: i guess this doesnt solve my issue. id shud be unique as i use the id to get data using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit confusing, so I'll answer from what I could understand.

You want to get Data from  whose id value is "permission".
The right syntax will be this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text"  id="permission" name="tenants" class="form-control">
```

Javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementById("permission").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like give below

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox" name="txtbox" value="" class="form-control">
<script>
    var x= document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

    //or you can use jquery if you want

    var x = $("#txtbox").val();
    ("#demo").html = x;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only execute the script on load, if you want to see in after change the inputs value by hand, you should add an event listener, but focusing in your example, the only thing you have to do is just giving your textbox a default value:

```js
 var x= document.getElementById("tenants").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="text" id="tenants" name="tenants" class="form-control" value="see??">
```